# Hubot in Terminal

Tags: javascript, heroku, osx-yosemite, hubot

I'm on a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.3, I'm writing my code in TextMate version 2.0-beta.7.4, and all of the heroku and hubot is the newest version.

In a class we had to install Hubot to our computer for local testing of code in terminal. Once that code is fine then we push it to Heroku and test it with another bot. Then if its fine with that bot the teacher pushes to git and we get to use Hubot in slack to show the code we made.

My problem is the code that I made isn't being seen by hubot in my terminal. What can I do to fix this so I can move on to the next step? All I've done is write the code and it never showed up to hubot in terminal.

When I tried pushing to Heroku before I was suppose to I got this error.

```
2015-06-26T16:56:00.521845+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Jun 26 2015 12:56:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR Unable to load /app/scripts/thisclass: /app/scripts/thisclass.js:1
```

My code for these files are JavaScript ended so .js

This is thisclass.js

```
// Description:
//   Explaining the class, program, and school.
//
// Dependencies:
//   None
//
// Configuration:
//   None
//
// Commands:
//   hubot dwp class - Explaining the class, program, and school.
//
// Author: 
//   Emily Van Vlerah
//
// Contributor:
//   None

module.exports = function(robot){
    // User types in command
    return robot.respond(/dwp class/i,function(msg){
        //The class information
        msg.send("This is the Deployment of Web Applications for the Web Design and Development program at Full Sail University.");
    });
}
```

My other file is that same exacept the information that would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

in the code you pasted you are missing a `;` at the very end